# About delegation in MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have some Model. In html view I have to reformate string model property for example more then 5 times. What part of MVC should do it? Friend say, that I must create Model method to do it, but my opinion is that View should response for that.

Comment: View method for formatting, model methods to get or manipulate model data. No formatting info in model methods, ever (but if you do it anyway the sun won't explode in a giant supernova - sometimes you break artificial, non-nature imposed rules merely to annoy people... :) ).

Comment: if it's bulky make a helper method. but  it's definitely view territory if you're formatting stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) or a **helper**. *Without seeing an example of your code it's hard to dig deeper.* But, yeah, keep the formatting for views out of the model.

Answer (score 1):

The model should be responsible for most aspects of data that you need including the business logic. Try to view it as the model being responsible for providing the correct data to the controllers which in turn pass this to the correct View to layout, format and style as required.

There is no reason you cannot add another layer or class library to deal with business logic without cluttering up the getter and setters in the main model.

Answer (score 1):

We have got the Table for example:

```
TableA:{
  Title:string;
  Description:string;
  Full-text:string;
}
```

and we decide to drop "**Description**" - and calculate it at the run time.

The point is "**Description**" - now is calculated property, so it belongs to Model, you could look at [calculated property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for example to understand what I mean.

But if u just do general formating like date -> to_cool_date u could use helpers. But if it`s calculated property -> it`s belong to model!